# regular expression for stop position in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, expression

I have a string: "0x1.9999999afpap-4". I hope to have a regular expression to extract 1.9999999afpa from this string. I am looking for a regular expression solution to extract everything from a string except the "0x" and "p-4". At meanwhile, I hope this solution could be applied to other strings with random letters and length, such as extract"1.999999999pp" from "0x1.999999999ppp-4"

Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you are trying to extract much more clearly. The regex that best matches `1.9999999af` is `1\.9999999af`. Also, what do you imagine `[$p]` does based on your interpretation of the docs?

Comment: I have edited my question to be more clear. I tried to use either [$p-4] or [^p..] to specify the stop position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a non-capturing group (note: you have to escape the dot to be accurate):

```
test ="0x1.9999999afp-4"
import re
new=re.search("1\.\w*(?=[$p])", test)
print (new.group())
```

now output is

```
"1.9999999af"
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a clue how "(?=[$p])" work? Does it mean that re.search will stop by p?

Comment: search won't capture p. stops by p or end of string.